# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException - 2019

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to automate my API & DB testing(postgresql) via Cucumber(Java).
How ever i have written my code and trying to execute below queries:

```java
resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from rules_data.postcode_leadtime where postcode = "+postcodedistrict.toUpperCase()+"  and order_type = "+ordertype.toUpperCase()+"");
```

Now, if i run the direct query i.e. -

```sql
select * 
from rules_data.postcode_leadtime 
where postcode = 'MK9'  
  and order_type = 'ADSI'
```

it runs perfectly fine but when I run the above query with parameters it gives the below error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "mk9" does not exist

I googled this up, found out that it has to be in Uppercase when executing the command, so then i made sure that its being converted into uppercase as you can see in the parameter in the above query, BUT STILL I AM GETTING THE SAME ISSUE. Happening for my other commands too.

Note: I have tried printing the values of parameters, they are coming in Upper cases.

Another issue i am getting is with the below query:

```java
resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select day from rules_data.hub_workdays where hub_id = " + hub + " and available = 'N'");
```

Over here hub is an integer value, it is coming fine on printing but when executing via Java gives an error below:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer

But when i run with value it works fine.

```sql
select day 
from rules_data.hub_workdays 
where hub_id = '593' 
and available = 'N'
```

Already mentioned in my first explanation.

Comment: Don't concatenate values into your SQL string. Use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead [passing](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) String values using `setString()` and integers using `setInt()`and then your problems will go away magically.

Comment: Hey a_horse_wth_no_name - I tried doing that but got an error running the PreparedStatement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use `PreparedStatement` as written in the comment, but your error can go away with the following fix:

```
resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from rules_data.postcode_leadtime 
                                 where postcode = '"+postcodedistrict.toUpperCase()+"'   
                                 and order_type = '"+ordertype.toUpperCase()+"'");
```

basically you need to add single quotes so that the parameters become `strings`

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept this answer by clicking in the check, on the left side.